# I need help storing and finding data in a .txt file

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am doing a project I found on a website, the website gave the task but did not give much information on how to do it.

Anyways, I basically need to make the program create a .txt file and stores a pupil's ULN (unique learner number), and a password in the file.

After it is made I need the program to search for certain ULN and passwords so the user can "login" (they would be prompted for ULN and Password later on in the Main class). If it isn't in the .txt file I need to output a message basically saying error.

The problems I have with this is:

1. The way I should store the new ULN and passwords so that they are linked, (so the password will only work with that ULN).
2. How I can make the program search through the .txt file for the ULN and its LINKED password.
3. How to tell the user if the ULN and password is not found.

Comment: Maybe you should use sqlce database instead of just a txt file so you can manipulate the data much better than a text file.

Answer (score 1):

If there are only a few records to store, you could create a DataTable with appropriate columns and serialize it to an xml file:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa.aspx

The example shows a DataSet but you can do it with just a DataTable.